# Detecting database changes in Django

Tags: mysql, django

I am trying to detect changes in database from my django app. For example, if entry in database table gets deleted, I need to call some function. So those changes goes not from the code, its done by user in db. Is there some module or something to detect those changes?
P.S. I have tried using signals, but not success

```
@receiver(post_delete, sender=TranslationsKeys)
def post_delete_merchant_active_translation(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print(f'Deleted {instance}')
```

Comment: Singals won't work. They are fired _internally_ by _python_ code, You would have to do something at the db level which causes it to write somewhere (or inform some process) when data is changed.

Comment: If you're using postgres check out: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/advanced.html#asynchronous-notifications

Comment: There is no built-in notification functionality within mysql. You would have to constantly poll your database for changes or you need to change your underlying infrastructure to use a database that has this feature or you cannot allow direct database edits by users and then you can use some kind of a message broker / queue to signal the changes to your django application.